# How to pass output of grep to sed with tail -f command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to filter out certain lines in a log file using the tail -f |grep command:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log |grep error
```

This works fine and I get a nice stream of errors only from the log.

The output of this has the entire date string at the beginning of each line eg. 07-Apr-2021

I want to filter out the first 11 characters of each line (07-Apr-2021)

So I have tried the following:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log |sed 's/...........//'
```

This works fine as well and removes the first 11 characters of each line.

So, I then tried the grep and sed together so I would get only error massages without the date at the beginning:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log |grep error |sed 's/...........//'
```

I get no output from this. I also tried:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log |sed 's/...........//' |grep error
```

Same again - no output. I don't get any errors I just get a blinking cursor with no output.
Obviously I am doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to fix OP's attempt here. Please try following. Couldn't test it because samples were not attached; should work though.

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log | grep --line-buffered "error" | sed -E 's/^.{11}//'
```

From `man grep`:

> --line-buffered
> Use line buffering on output.

Also I have fixed your `sed`'s substitution here, you need not mention 11 dots here you could handle that with regex like I shown above.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Within single `awk` you could do following.

```
tail -f Input_file | awk '/error/{sub(/^.{11}/,"");print;fflush()}'
```

Comment: You don't need the flush here as long as Awk is not writing to a pipe. The buffering problem happens when standard output is a pipe.

Comment: @tripleee, so it should be something like `tail -f file | awk '/error/{sub(/^.{11}/,"");print;fflush()}'` to use fflush if I get it correctly here, to keep on printing values. EDIT: I just tested it with increasing lines `tail -f file1 | awk '/error/{sub(/^.{11}/,"");print;fflush()}'` and it works fine, let me edit my solution now.

Comment: After googling around I realize this also depends on your Awk version. What I was trying to say is that you could perhaps omit the `fflush()` after the `print` but now I'm not entirely sure that's robust and portable.

Comment: @tripleee, I just tested it with increasing lines `tail -f file1 | awk '/error/{sub(/^.{11}/,"");print;fflush()}'` and it works fine, let me edit my solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I have found that the reason I wasn't getting an output is that I needed to use --line-buffered for the grep (thanks ravindersingh13). In regards to the sed command this is what I ended up using and worked:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log | grep --line-buffered "error" | sed -r 's/{11}//'
```

This removes the first 11 characters of the grep output.

Comment: The `sed` command liiks broken; you hre missing a dot before `{11}`. The problem with `-E` or `-r` is that these are not portable.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) might also be an option, and arguably more elegant.

```sh
tail -f /path/to/file.log |
sed -n '/error/s/...........//p'
```